# xmlhttp.responseText not outputting to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, innerhtml

I'm trying to familiarize myself with Ajax as I will need to use it continually for work.  I'm working through the W3Schools tutorial trying things with my Apache2 server.  I have a file called ajax_info.txt on the server (under /var/www (ubuntu)).  I'm making a call to it and with Firebug I see I get a good response (4 & 200) but it isn't outputting the contents of the file to the DOM.  Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var xmlhttp;
        var url = "http://192.168.0.5/ajax_info.txt";

        function loadXMLDoc(url, cfunc) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc;
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        function myFunction() {
            loadXMLDoc(url, function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">
            <h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2>
        </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Change Content</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not exactly sure what it is I'm doing wrong.  The w3schools tutorial isn't exhaustive by any stretch.  I plan on buying a book, but I'd love to learn these simple GET calls as it will get me headed in the proper direction.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you use this instead? document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = 'test';

Comment: Not the problem, but if you're going to code `loadXMLDoc()` so that it accepts a callback, why not do all the `readyState` and `status` checks _before_ calling the callback function? Just call it on success passing the result as a parameter. (Note: your code would be easier to read and therefore easier to debug if you used a better indentation scheme...)

Comment: Is your page also being served from `http://192.168.0.5/`? If not, it'll likely see it as a cross-domain request.

Comment: w3schools often has incorrect information or bad practices. See w3fools.com

Comment: oh crap...yeah the page is local.  I completely overlooked that issue.  I'll jump on the server and add the page to the webserver and give it another shot.

Comment: Yup....it was a cross domain issue.  I put the html file on the web server and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
function ajax(x) {

            var a;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                a = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                a = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } else {
                alert("Browser Dosent Support Ajax! ^_^");
            }


            if (a !== null) {
                a.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (a.readyState < 4) {
                        //document.getElementById('cnt').innerHTML = "Progress";
                    } else if (a.readyState === 4) {
                        //respoce recived
                        var res = a.responseText;

                        document.getElementById('center_scrolling_div').innerHTML = res;
                        eval(document.getElementById('center_scrolling_div').innerHTML);
                    }
                };

                a.open("GET", x, true);
                a.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                a.send();


            }

        }
```